# Change the tail traingle color in the tooltip in leaflet

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I am trying to change the tooltip tail triangle color on mouseover of the leaflet map marker pin but I can't inspect the exact class name to override it. Is there a way to change the color and need to move the position of the triangle to left side of the marker image and also the css classname. This post shows the exact requirement for popup and I need for tooltip.

```
const tooltipOptions = {
        direction: 'top',
        offset: [0, -44],
        // className: 'leaflet-tooltip-tip', -- tried adding the class to change the color but didnt help.
      };
      onMouseOverEvent.bindTooltip('My tooltip', tooltipOptions).openTooltip();
```

Comment: Spend some time inspecting pseudo-elements. Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285588/why-does-the-classname-option-of-a-leaflet-popup-change-only-the-outside-of-the/285662 .

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the css class name of tooltip with the help of debugger in the dev tools console with `setTimeout(()=> {debugger}, 3000)` and then inspected the elements to check the class and modified as below

```
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
    border-top-color: red !important;
}
```